# docker-compose how to persist mongodb-database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using docker-compose and here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  node:
    container_name: my-app
    image: my-app
    build:
      context: ./my-app-directoty
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run dev
    environment:
      MONGO_URL: my-database
      port: 3000
    volumes:
      - ./my-app-directory/src:/app/src
      - ./my-app-directory/node_modules:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    depends_on:
      - my-database

  my-database:
    container_name: my-database
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - my-app-network

networks:
  my-app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I expect to find a clear and newly created database each time I run the following command:

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

But this is not the case. When I bring the containers up with `docker-compose up`, my database has the exact state of the last time I shut it down with `docker-compose down` command. And since I have not specified a `volume` prop in `my-database` object, is this normal behaviour? Does this mean that no other action to persisting database state is required? And can I use this in production if I ever choose to use `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mongo image define the following volumes:

- `/data/configdb`
- `/data/db`

So `docker-volume` will create and use a unamed volume for `data/db`.

If you want to have a new one, use:

```sh
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Or use a mount point mounted on the volume location like:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./db:/data/db:rw
```

And drop your local `db` directories when you want to start over.